# How to convert screen coordinates to coordinates on a z transformed element?

Tags: javascript, 3d, css-transforms, coordinate-transformation

I have a z transformed element that has a marker as a child and I need to put that marker at the mouse click position.

I need to know how to convert screen coordinates to coordinates on z transformed element.

Here is my current code:

```js
function getPosition(screenCoords)
{
    // This function should return x and y coordinates on z-transformed element and I have no idea how to achieve that.
    
    return {x: 2500, y: 1500};
}

var $viewport = $(".viewport");
var $marker = $(".marker");
    
$viewport.on("click", function(e){
        
    e.preventDefault();
        
    var newMarkerPosition = getPosition({x: e.pageX, y: e.pageY});
        
    $marker.css({
        left: newMarkerPosition.x + "px", 
        top: newMarkerPosition.y + "px"
    });
        
});
```

```css
html, body {
    
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    
}

.viewport {
    
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    
    perspective: 1000px;
    perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
}

.z-transformed-element {
    
    width: 5000px;
    height: 3000px;
    transform-origin: 2500px 1500px;
    background-color: gray;
    position: relative;
    
    transform: translateX(-2500px) translateY(-1500px) translateZ(-10000px);
    
}

.marker {
    
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin-left: -100px;
    margin-top: -100px;
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="viewport">
    <div class="z-transformed-element">
        <div class="marker"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The toughest part here seems to be the conversion of the screen-space coordinates of a click to the transformed coordinates. One way you can do this is to use the [`getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) function (which returns the dimensions/position of an object after all transformations are applied), and use its dimensions to calculate the ratio between the displayed dimensions of an element, and their "actual" dimensions.

Once you have this ratio, just multiply it with the click coordinates (after offsetting them to be relative to the element's displayed center coordinates) to get the transformed click coordinates.

I've added to your code to show how you can use this approach to move your CSS-transformed element to the mouse click position:

```js
function getPosition(screenCoords)
{
    var $transformedEl = $(".z-transformed-element");
    
    // Calculating "actual" center of element
    var elementCenter = {
        x: $transformedEl.innerWidth() / 2,
        y: $transformedEl.innerHeight() / 2
    }
    
    // Determining ratio of displayed dimensions to "actual" dimensions
    var boundingRect = $transformedEl[0].getBoundingClientRect();
    var dimRatio = $transformedEl.innerWidth() / boundingRect.width;
    
    // Determining offset click coordinates (relative to displayed center of element)
    var clickOffset = {
        x: screenCoords.x - $transformedEl.offset().left - boundingRect.width / 2,
        y: screenCoords.y - $transformedEl.offset().top - boundingRect.height / 2
    }
    
    // Calculating coordinates of click, relative to element's "actual" center and ratio of displayed to "actual" dimensions
    var finalCoords = {
     x: elementCenter.x + clickOffset.x * dimRatio,
     y: elementCenter.y + clickOffset.y * dimRatio
    }
    
    return finalCoords;
}

var $viewport = $(".viewport");
var $marker = $(".marker");
    
$viewport.on("click", function(e){
        
    e.preventDefault();
    
    console.log(e.pageX, e.pageY);
    
    var newMarkerPosition = getPosition({x: e.pageX, y: e.pageY});
        
    $marker.css({
        left: newMarkerPosition.x + "px", 
        top: newMarkerPosition.y + "px"
    });
        
});
```

```css
html, body {
    
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    
}

.viewport {
    
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    
    perspective: 1000px;
    perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
}

.z-transformed-element {
    
    width: 5000px;
    height: 3000px;
    transform-origin: 2500px 1500px;
    background-color: gray;
    position: relative;
    
    transform: translateX(-2500px) translateY(-1500px) translateZ(-10000px);
    
}

.marker {
    
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin-left: -100px;
    margin-top: -100px;
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="viewport">
    <div class="z-transformed-element">
        <div class="marker"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

(I admit that finding the simplest approach was hard for me - I almost went the route of trying to transform the coordinates with transformation matrices! Gah.)

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Works like a charm! Didn't knew about getBoundingClientRect(). It seems to make things way easier. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad I could help out! This was a bit of a learning experience for me too.

Comment: But now I tried to rotate the element and it started calculated coordinates wrong. Can you come up with something that works for rotated element as well? I'm interested in rotateX and rotateY.

Comment: @GiedriusT Unfortunately, I suspect that broadens the scope of the question a fair bit (my original thought to using transformation matrices might not be overkill now). Consider making a new question for this?

Comment: OK, I will make a new question regarding this.